get_query_var returns wrong value
I create a rewrite rule with different params

add_rewrite_rule(
    '^shop/(\b(thanks)\b)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$', 
    'index.php?pagename=shop&shop_endpoint=$matches[1]&ref=$matches[2]&key=$matches[3]', 
    'top'
);

add_filter('query_vars', function($vars){
    $vars[] = 'shop_endpoint';
    $vars[] = 'ref';
    $vars[] = 'key';
    return $vars;       
}, 10, 1);

I have the following url
https://www.example.com/shop/thanks/2956789/6212/
If I dump
get_query_var('schop_endpoint');
get_query_var('ref');
get_query_var('key');

the output is

thanks
thanks
thanks

and not

thanks
2956789
6212

I does not see the mistake who can help me a little?

Are you telling us the truth about the currently flawed output?  I see $m[1] is the word boundary wrapped capture -- thanks. $m[2] is the word in the nested capture -- thanks. $m[3] is the number. $m[4] is the last number.  Is this just a typo  question where you remove the excess capture group (and the pointless word boundaries)?  Also, [0-9] is more simply written as \d.

I think the problem is \b present in your regex, which is causing the whole output to be thanks.
Corrected code:
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^shop/(thanks)/(\d+)/(\d+)$', 
    'index.php?pagename=shop&shop_endpoint=$matches[1]&ref=$matches[2]&key=$matches[3]', 
    'top'
);

add_filter('query_vars', function($vars){
    $vars[] = 'shop_endpoint';
    $vars[] = 'ref';
    $vars[] = 'key';
    return $vars;       
}, 10, 1);

Also, I have changed [0-9] to \d for simplicity (as recommended by @mickmackusa in the comments of question).
Hope this helps.
